# How to change the theme of Ubuntu 13.10 in Ubuntu builder to mac OSx Lion

Tags: 13.10, macosx

I am making an iso of Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit with the Mac OSx theme. I screwed up and had to start all over, but before I screwed up I couldn't open Ubuntu tweak, Unity tweak, or Gnome tweak. I have everything set except the actual theme, can anyone help me with this? I booted up to Ubuntu 12.04 to make Saucy with mac theme in ubuntu builder.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save it to a flashdrive and set it to have 2500MB of space reserved. then change the OS to look like a mac.